# How to combine JSP fragments into seamless table regardless of ordering

Tags: html, css, jsp, struts2

I have multiple JSPs that each contain one or more tables.

**fragment1.jsp:**

```
<table class="foo">
  <tr>
    <td>stuff</td> <td>stuff2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**fragment2.jsp**

```
<table class="foo">
  <tr>
    <td>more stuff</td> <td>more stuff2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="bar">
  <tr>
    <td>whatever</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

They are used by wrappers in different configurations:

**wrapper1.jsp**

```
<s:include value="fragment1.jsp" />
<s:include value="fragment2.jsp" />
```

**wrapper2.jsp**

```
<s:include value="fragment2.jsp" />
```

If `fragment2.jsp` comes after `fragment1.jsp`, I want these two tables to have no margin between them and appear as one table. However, if either one is alone, I want them to be formatted normally as `"foo"` tables are styled.

Is there a way to indicate this styling preference in some way such that the two `"foo"` tables will appear as a single table when adjacent, but otherwise style themselves normally?

I am somewhat new to Struts/JSP and dealing with some kludged legacy code, so please help me understand if this problem would be better solved through another approach.

Comment: Why not to add css that removes margin?

Comment: Do you want multiple tables in the same fragment to collapse too, or only "boundary" tables between different fragments ?

Comment: Basically if I end up with two or more "foo" class tables next to each other, I want to mash them together, but otherwise I want them to be separated normally.

Comment: I've posted an answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually possible with CSS only, *without* JavaScript and *without* changing the HTML.

> *A **[full screen demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/hp4u3y1o/embedded/result/)** is worth a thousand words...*

Basically, you need to use `border-collapse: collapse;` and specify the following settings:

1. When the table is alone, all the borders and margins normally set:

   ```
   table {
       border-collapse : collapse;
                border : 4px solid black;
            margin-top : 20px;
         margin-bottom : 20px;
   }
   ```
2. When the table is adjacent to one or more other tables:

   - If it's not the first, **remove `margin-top` and `border-top`:**

     ```
     table + table {
         margin-top : 0;
         border-top : none;
     }
     ```
   - If it's not the last: **remove `margin-bottom` and `border-bottom`:**

     ```
     table:not(:last-child) {
         border-bottom : none;
         margin-bottom : 0;
     }
     ```

Also ensure to avoid setting a border on the last `<tr>` of each table:

```
tr:not(:last-child) {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use javascript and jquery for doing such works. So I think this can be helpful:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var secondTable = $(".bar").html();
     $(".foo").append(secondTable);
});
```

Note, you need to include jquery library if you have not included it already.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, hamed. In our case, the container files are assembling blocks of partial HTML and I think it would be difficult to restructure them to use your approach, but it certainly seems useful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use tables if you don't use tabular data. You can always use `div` or `span` tags.

```
<div class="foo">
  <span>more stuff</span> <span>more stuff2</span>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <span>whatever</span>
</div>
```

Comment: In general I agree, though in this case we are displaying tabular data so the use of tables is not totally out of line. My sample example doesn't make this terribly clear, but I appreciate your sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS selector `table.foo + table.foo` will select every element of `table.foo` that appears after another element of the same type.
You can use it to remove the margin from **all** following `table.foo` elements:

```
table.foo + table.foo {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

If it should apply to the **second** element only, use `table.foo:nth-child(2)` instead.

Comment: This looks promising. Is there a way to format all table.foo to have no top margin EXCEPT the top one?

Comment: Stefan, thank you very much for the answer. I selected Andrea's as the chosen answer as I believe those examples will be helpful for future visitors, but I appreciate your response.

Comment: This is half of the solution, and has a drawback: with two or more tables, the last table will lose the margin-bottoms too, while it shouldn't. The `+` (adjacent sibling selector) should be used to alter the **top** settings only; for altering the **bottom** settings the `:not` and `:last-child` selectors are the cleanest way. But at least it is in the right direction